# Custom markers not visible in mapbox-android

Tags: android, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I'm using mapbox-sdk android for location tracking. I want to add few custom markers to the map in specified location. But the below code doesn't works for me.

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
options.title("pos");
IconFactory iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
Icon icon = iconFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.home);
options.icon(icon);
options.position(new LatLng(80.27, 13.09));
mapboxMap.addMarker(options);
```

I use mapox-sdk:6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
private fun addMarkerIconsToMap(loadedMapStyle: Style) {
    BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.red_marker))?.let {
        loadedMapStyle.addImage("icon-id", it)
    }
    if(!locationList.isNullOrEmpty()){
        val feature: ArrayList<Feature> = ArrayList()
        for (x in 0 until locationList.size){
            feature.add(Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(locationList[x].long, locationList[x].lat)))
        }
        loadedMapStyle.addSource(GeoJsonSource("source-id",
            FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(feature)
            )
        )
        loadedMapStyle.addLayer(SymbolLayer("layer-id", "source-id").withProperties(
            iconImage("icon-id"),
            iconOffset(arrayOf(0f, -8f))
            )
        )
    }
}
```

inside locationList is Array of long: Double and lat: Double

YourActivity :

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    private lateinit var mapboxMap: MapboxMap
    ...
    
}
```

and then override :

```
override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS){
        addMarkerIconsToMap(it)
    }

    this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would add a custom marker (from a Compose perspective).
(You can either do it from the viewModel depending on your program structure)

```
 AndroidView(
    factory = { mapView }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()        
) { mView ->
    val bitmap = bitmapFromDrawableRes(context, R.drawable.chicken_marker)!!
    val annotation = mView.annotations
    val pointManager = annotation.createPointAnnotationManager()
    
    list.forEach { point ->
        val pointOptions = PointAnnotationOptions()
            .withPoint(point)
            .withIconImage(bitmap)

        pointManager.create(pointOptions.apply { iconSize = 0.8 })
    }
```

Here's the functions used to get the drawable(".svg",".png",".jpeg")

```
private fun bitmapFromDrawableRes(context: Context, @DrawableRes resourceId: Int): Bitmap? =
    convertDrawableToBitmap(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, resourceId))

private fun convertDrawableToBitmap(sourceDrawable: Drawable?): Bitmap? {
    if (sourceDrawable == null) {
        return null
    }
    return if (sourceDrawable is BitmapDrawable) {
        sourceDrawable.bitmap
    } else {
// copying drawable object to not manipulate on the same reference
        val constantState = sourceDrawable.constantState ?: return null
        val drawable = constantState.newDrawable().mutate()
        val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        bitmap
    }
}
```